# MySQL - How to store multiple combinations of colors for one product?

Tags: mysql, database, join, combinations

I am searching for the best solution for the following issue:

I have three tables:

1. Product

| id | productName |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Tshirt |
| 2 | Pullover |
| 3 | Jacket |

2. Base Color

| id | baseColorName | allowedExtraColorIds |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Green | 1,2 |
| 2 | Blue | 2,3 |
| 3 | Red | 3 |

3. Extra Color

| id | extraColorName |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Purple |
| 2 | Orange |
| 3 | Black |

So as you can see, there is a dependency between the tables Base and Extra Color.

- So not each Extra Color can be used with each Base Color. For the Base Color "Green" only the Extra Colors with the Ids "1 and 2" are allowed to pick.

Now the Table Product contains the products. However I now want to have a form where the user can first select the product and then he can map combinations of Base and Extra Colors to this product.

**Example:**

1. The user selects the "Tshirt" as a product
2. Now he creates Combinations:

- He selects the Base Color "Green" and he selects the allowed Extra Color "Purple"
- He selects the Base Color "Red" and he selects the allowed Extra Color "Black"

And now I am wondering how to save this information, so the mapping of the different combinations of Base and Extra Colors for the single product in a MySql Database.

Has anyone an idea how to achieve this? :)

Comment: Always avoid DELIMITED LISTS, they will cause you extra pain later when you come to use them. Create a cross reference table which is the Relational database way of linking things like this. A simple table with 2 columns `base_id` and `extra_id` can be all you need

Comment: You could also use one to link `product` to `base colour` as you dont currently seem to have a link there either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create tables like below to store generated combinations.

1. selected_products

   | id | product_id | user_id |
   | --- | --- | --- |
   | 1 | 1 | 1 |
   | 2 | 2 | 1 |
2. selected_product_combinations

   | id | selected_product_id | base_color_id | extra_color_id |
   | --- | --- | --- | --- |
   | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
   | 2 | 1 | 3 | 3 |

Here, selected_product_id is a foreign-key reference to the primary key of selected_products table.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I think this should do it for my case. :)

Answer (score 1):

Elaborating a bit on what @RiggsFolly already suggested:

- work with 1 table of colors. Having two of them will only complexify the situation
- create a table where all possible combinations are listed as individual items - you could even consider adding the product to allow scenarios where not all colors are available for all products.

Like this

| Product | Basecolor | Extracolor |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | 2 |

That way, all checks become a simple singleton query that either gives a result (combination allowed) or doesn't (combination not allowed)

This will change your approach a bit but as said, that's how you do things with RDBMS's. It will save you a lot of headaches afterwards.

Yes, to propose all possible combinations you will retrieve a result set instead of one record, but that is easily solved.

Comment: I would disagree with the use of only one table as 1. _The product has a BaseColour._ and then 2. _The product MAY have a ExtraColour_ but that in not the case for all products

Comment: @RiggsFolly having two tables with colors, especially in real world scenarios where there could be dozens or hundreds of colors seems inefficient to me - and a nightmare of you want to translate colornames for i18n. That's not related to basecolor and extracolor, however it will lead to the introduction of a dummy color meaning "not allowed" to get a result in any case. I should add that to the answer or do you have a better idea?

Comment: Thanks for your ideas. However I think, that I need the two tables for Base and Extra Colors. The reason for that is: The table "Extra Color" includes just Colors. The "Base Color" Table includes also a field with the allowed Extra Colors. I would therefore not know how to merge these two tables